# create hyper links dynamically when transforming xml to xsl-fo using xlst?

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, xsl-fo

I want to create a heading in my PDF report using my xsl file. If the source file contains a hyperlink then it should render it as hyperlink, otherwise as plain text.

For example, my xml looks like:

```
<a href='http://google.com' target='_blank'>This is the heading </a>"
```

It should display a hyperlink if there is one, otherwise display the heading as plain text.
How can I do that?

I am not able to use the below code under otherwise tag , please see below

```
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="($RTL='true') or ($RTL='True')">
      <fo:block wrap-option="wrap" hyphenate="true"  text-align="right" font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:value-of select="@friendlyname" />
      </fo:block>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <!--<fo:block wrap-option="wrap" hyphenate="true"  font-weight="bold">-->
      <xsl:template match="a">
        <fo:block>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@href">
              <fo:basic-link>
                <xsl:attribute name="external-destination">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="@friendlyname"  />
              </fo:basic-link>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="@friendlyname"  />
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </fo:block>

      </xsl:template>

      <!--<xsl:value-of select="@friendlyname"  />-->

      <!--</fo:block>-->
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
```

How can I use it there?

Comment: This is an incorrect way of using the `xsl:template` element. It cannot be inside an `otherwise`. So, now (i.e. since you updated your question), your problem has nothing to do with basic links, but with basic rules for writing XSLT code.

Answer (score 1):

To display a link in XSL-FO, use `fo:basic-link`. See [the relevant part of the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_basic-link) for details.

This creates a simple, clickable link without any formatting otherwise. That is, the format is inherited from the surrounding block element. So, if your links should be underlined or shown in blue, you have to specify this explicitly. For instance, by using a `fo:inline` element.

Now, in terms of XSLT code, if you encounter `a` elements:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
 <fo:block><!--This is the heading block-->
```

Test whether there is a `href` attribute or not:

```
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@href">
      <fo:basic-link>
        <xsl:attribute name="external-destination">
          <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </fo:basic-link>
    </xsl:when>
```

On the other hand, if there is no such attribute:

```
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </fo:block>

</xsl:template>
```

Basic links can have either an external or internal destination. The latter is used to refer to specific chapters from the table of contents, for example.

Comment: Every time it's coming in otherwise condition and never picks up hyperlink? This is my actual value <a href='http://google.com' target='_blank'>This is the heading </a>

Comment: I commented on your original post. You inserted my answer in the wrong place, it seems. The `xsl:choose` only works as intended if the surrounding template matches `a` elements.

Comment: Thanks, Mathias for your help. It seems to be working well except I am not getting the proper link from below code  <xsl:when test="contains(@friendlyname, 'href')">
                <fo:basic-link> 
                  <xsl:attribute name="external-destination">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@friendlyname"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:call-template name="remove-html">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@friendlyname"/>
                  </xsl:call-template>
                </fo:basic-link>
              </xsl:when> my input isat top

Comment: @friendlyname is <a href='http://google.com' target='_blank'>This is the heading </a> and I need just hyperlink from that, can you please help me to do that?

Comment: The code I have shown you does _exactly_ that. But I'd saresay that instead of asking questions you should look at an introduction to XSLT for a few minutes - this will help you understand my answers.