# get href value from hyperlink in xslt

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt, xml-parsing

How can I get only `href` value in xslt , below if my input from xml .

```
<a href='http://google.com' target='_blank'>This is the heading </a>
```

I only need `href` value to create a link.

Comment: Why don't you use the answer I have given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328634/create-hyper-links-dynamically-when-transforming-xml-to-xsl-fo-using-xlst/21329825?noredirect=1#comment32233929_21329825 - instead of asking exactly the same again?

Comment: I have tried that but that's not working at all, you can try with above link if it gives you the href value

Comment: It doesn't recognize href because it's not a separate filed in my XMl and is a part of title tag within hyperlink

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not recognize href"? Or by "part of title tag within hyperlink"?

Comment: I am new to XSL. if you can give me a simple working version which generate link from above code that would be great. I need to know how we will call this template, Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: To your answer, when I write  <xsl:attribute name="external-destination">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>, it doesn't get the value of @href so it gives error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following stylesheet. This is *exactly* what I have described in an earlier question of yours.

> I need to know how we will call this template

The template that matches `a` elements is called by an `xsl:apply-templates` statement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <fo:root>

  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple"
                  page-height="29.7cm"
                  page-width="21cm"
                  margin-top="1cm"
                  margin-bottom="2cm"
                  margin-left="2.5cm"
                  margin-right="2.5cm">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="3cm"/>
      <fo:region-before extent="3cm"/>
      <fo:region-after extent="1.5cm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple">

    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

      <fo:block font-size="18pt"
            font-family="sans-serif"
            line-height="24pt"
            space-after.optimum="15pt"
            background-color="blue"
            color="white"
            text-align="center"
            padding-top="3pt">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </fo:block>


      <!-- this defines normal text -->
      <fo:block font-size="12pt"
                font-family="sans-serif"
                line-height="15pt"
                space-after.optimum="3pt"
                text-align="justify">
        The Extensible Markup Language (XML) is a subset of SGML that is completely described in this document. Its goal is to
        enable generic SGML to be served, received, and processed on the Web in the way that is now possible with HTML. XML
        has been designed for ease of implementation and for interoperability with both SGML and HTML.
      </fo:block>

    </fo:flow> <!-- closes the flow element-->
  </fo:page-sequence> <!-- closes the page-sequence -->
</fo:root>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="a">
      <fo:basic-link>
           <xsl:attribute name="external-destination">
             <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
           </xsl:attribute>
           <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </fo:basic-link>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input XML:

```
<a href='http://google.com' target='_blank'>This is the heading </a>
```

Using XSLT 2.0, Saxon and Apache FOP 1.0, you get the correct output, a clickable heading:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Is it a feature of XSL 2.0 and will not work in 1.0? I was trying it in 1.0 as we have that version with us.

Comment: Should work, too. Just modifiy the code to `version="1.0"`. Also, please consider accepting both questions (mark the tick on the left of the answer).

Comment: It still doesn't work for me, Is there any way so I can send you my XML and XSL file so you can check?

Comment: No. I am not willing to invest in further explanations, this is straightforward enough and I spent a lot of time on this already. Remember that people are helping you for free. Instead, read a book or tutorial on XSLT (apparently, you do not understand it well yet) - and you will be able to understand the answers I gave.