# <a href> link in XML file, how to use in XSL file?

Tags: xml, xslt

So, I have this XML document that looks like any other, except it has links in it, which is also the issue. When I run xsl:value-of , I do get the value in itself but the text thats suppoed to become a hyperlink doesn't. How do I get this to work?

**The XML code:**

```
<Response>
    <Reminders>
        <Reminder>
                <ReminderLong>Sample Text with a link <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">here</a></ReminderLong>
        </Reminder>
    </Reminders>
</Response>
```

**The current XSL code (tried a lot of different versions of this to try to get the links to work, but this is what I am sitting on right now, keep in mind I am very much a newbie at this) :**

```
<xsl:for-each select="Response/Reminders/Reminder">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="ReminderLong" /></p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**The XSL code binding stylesheets and whatnot**

```
<?xml
version="1.0"
encoding="UTF-8"
?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="/">
```

**What I expect:**

```
<p>Sample Text with a link <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">here</a></p>
```

**What it does:**

```
<p>Sample Text with a link here</p>
```

Comment: can u paste your XML and xsl here?

Comment: I cannot, nope. Wouldn't the eventual fix apply to anything though? All I am looking at is how to let the <xsl:value-of> command know theres a link in there to, that it has to execute. Quite surprising HTML didn't automatically pick that up.

Comment: isnt this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328634/create-hyper-links-dynamically-when-transforming-xml-to-xsl-fo-using-xlst/21329825?noredirect=1#comment32233929_21329825

Comment: Could very well be, cant get that working right now but will have a look at it. @Meghaa

Comment: @Xariez "*Wouldn't the eventual fix apply to anything though?*" No. It's not at all clear what you have or what you want to have. Post a small example of the XML input and the expected result of transforming it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Okay, I mean, the more you know I guess.. Example of that coming up in just a moment!

Comment: @Xariez Please post the exact code you expect to get as the result of the transformation. I, for one, have no idea what "text with a link" means. Is your output HTML?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I will go ahead and do that right now then, and Yes, it is HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="Reminder">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Tried that, but getting: "Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed." once I refresh the site. Seems to be complaining on just about everything, since I got to remove all of it for it to work. Not sure if it matters, but above the <html> starting tag I've got some stylesheet commands as well, posted in the original post.

Comment: @Xariez See it working here: http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYi1 This is a complete stylesheet - if you change it, it may easily break.

Comment: Asked before how to get HTML/CSS in there, little did I know that will now be sorted inside the template elements as far as I understand it. Cheers for the help! :) Nevermind: Just realised that everything now gets looped thats inside there. Kind of an issue.